# Read in times from Excel in R

Tags: r, excel

I have data saved in Excel that includes time data.

When reading it in with read.xlsx in R, it adds "1899-12-30" to the time column, I presume in an attempt to read in a date in addition to the time that doesn't exist.

```
library(xlsx)

times<-read.xlsx("times.xlsx", sheetName = "Sheet1")
times
             Time
1 1899-12-30 20:13:24
2 1899-12-30 08:13:54
3 1899-12-30 08:14:24
4 1899-12-30 08:14:54
5 1899-12-30 08:15:24
```

I tried

```
times<-read.xlsx("times.xlsx", sheetName = "Sheet1", colClasses('POSIXct'))
```

and

```
times<-read.xlsx("times.xlsx", sheetName = "Sheet1", colClasses('POSIXct(format='%H:%M:%S')'))
```

but the first doesn't do anything and the second gives me an error.

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for `xlsx::read.xlsx`?  There's a suggestion of how to handle POSIXct conversion

Comment: I did and I tried some of the suggestions, but they didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `read.xlsx()` recognizes TIME as `%H:%M:%S`, and converts it into the dummy POSIXct/POSIXt object, i.e. 1899-12-31 08:00:00 and 1899-12-31 20:00:00

```
#use readxl
library(readxl)
df <- read_excel('test.xlsx')
```

OR use `format`

```
read.xlsx("myfile.xlsx") %>%
  mutate(
    TIME = format(TIME, "%I:%M %p")
    )
```

OR after reading `df` convert it into time using

```
as.POSIXct(df$Time, format="%H:%M:%S", tz="CET")
```

EDIT:
     I don't have data to replicate your errors or problem that you are facing , so i have made one according to those date format

```
df = data.frame(Time = c("1899-12-30 20:13:24","1899-12-30 08:13:54","1899-12-30 08:14:24","1899-12-30 08:14:54","1899-12-30 08:15:24"))

df <- as.POSIXct(df$Time, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M") #apply  function to create a POSIXct object

#use the `strftime()` function to split the column and then the function times() to create a chronological object.
library(chron)
time <- times(strftime(df, format="%H:%M:%S"))
```

This method should def work, hope you got the idea there are many ways to achieve this

Comment: I'd already tried converting it after import, but even if I only specify "%H:%M:%S" it still showed the dummy dates. So does read_excel. Mutate gives me an error

Comment: Thank you! strftime seems to mess up the times, though. It adds 13.5 hrs (or subtracts 11.5?). 20:13 -> 09:43. 8:13 -> 21:43. Not quite sure why. I was suspecting a timezone conflict, but what with the half hour?

Comment: Nevermind, adding tz="GMT" to strftime fixed it. Still not sure what's up with the half hour. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a way to convert it back to POSIX?I tried both as.POSIXct and as.POSIXlt but it's giving me an error. I later on need to floor the times to the hour,but floor_date only works with POSIX